# Non-Dimensionalization Mathematica

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, nonlinear-functions, dimensionality-reduction

I have a set of coupled equations for the variables `H`, `W`, `P`, & `T` (below) that I need to non-dimensionalize. Is there a way of achieving this in Mathematica as doing it manually is proving difficult.

```
{(a 1/(1 + R T[t]) - b) H[t] - (ap + bp) P[t] - bt T[t] == H'[t],

 L P[t] - g W[t] - B W[t] H[t] == W'[t],

 B  W[t] H[t] - (up + b + bp + bt T[t]/H[t]) P[t] - 
   bp (P[t]^2)/H[t] ((k + 1)/k) + phi T[t] == P'[t],

 H[t] (theta) - (b + bp P[t]/H[t] + bt ) T[t] - 
   bt (T[t]^2)/H[t] ((k + 1)/k) - v P[t] == T'[t]}
```

Parameter units: a = /H/unit time; b = /H/unit time; B = /H/unit time; theta = T/H/unit time; ap = /P/unit time; bp = /P/unit time; up = /P/unit time; v = /P/unit time; L = W/P/unit time; R = /T/unit time; bt = /T/unit time; phi = /T/unit time; g = /W/unit time; k = constant.

Comment: If you mean to make equation dimensionless, then you need to tell us dimensions of each variable involved in the equation. Then the best way to do it, is to use ReplaceAll (/.) to replace each variable with itself multiplied by dimension units. If dimension units at the end of the day factor out, your equations can be made dimensionless

Comment: Of course, thanks Sasha. Parameter units: a = /H/unit time;
b = /H/unit time;
B = /H/unit time;

theta = T/H/unit time;

ap = /P/unit time;
bp = /P/unit time;
up = /P/unit time;
v = /P/unit time;

L = W/P/unit time;

R = /T/unit time;
bt = /T/unit time;
phi = /T/unit time;

g = /W/unit time;


k = constant. H,T,P and W are variables

Comment: @belisarius. Excellent, will do. p.s Is there a way of editing the original question (I want to add the units as Sasha kindly suggested into the original question). Thanks kindly for the link to the Pi-theorem file.. but i suspect it might start to be beyond my expertise to it understand completely enough to get an answer i trust :/

Comment: there is a small "edit" link right under the question. Or follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5461090/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**This package**](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/763/DimLessGuideAndCode.nb?file_id=1436) may help you to use the Pi-theorem.

I never used it, though.

Comment: @Mary yes, it works. I'm trying it right now. The problem is that doesn't load straight from my pointer. Try this http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/763/

Comment: I must agree that it does not work. :^)  I made and edit, let's see if it gets approved.

Comment: oh yes, found it now, thanks. I will try and see if I can apply it.